# Perl WWW:Mechanize Form fill does not work

Tags: forms, perl, authentication, fill, www-mechanize

I have some nice problems with filling out a login form with WWW::Mechanize.

First, I will show you the part of the website, which unfotunatelly is in german:

```
<form action="/login.php" method="post" onsubmit="md5pass();">
<p><br/></p>
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="border:dotted 1px black">
    <tr bgcolor="#ffb442" align="center">
        <td colspan="2">
            <p></p><b>Bitte <a href="http://www.xyz.de/startseite.php">Flirtlife</a> Usernamen und Passwort eingeben!</b></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffae35">
        <td>
            <b>Username: &nbsp;</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="user" size="25" maxlength="40" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="relocate" value="/profil.php?user=1180038">          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffae35">
        <td>
            <b>Passwort: </b>
        </td><td>
            <input type="password" id="passwd" name="passwd" size="25" maxlength="32">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffae35">
        <td>
            <b>Autologin: </b>
        </td><td>
            <input onclick="toggle('hinweis_setautologin', 'setautologin');" type="checkbox" id="setautologin" name="setautologin" value="true"> automatisch einloggen
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" id="hinweis_setautologin" style="background:#fff;font-size:9px;display:none;" bgcolor="#ffae35">
             Du wirst solange automatisch eingeloggt bis du auf LOGOUT klickst oder auf einem anderen Rechner das AUTOLOGIN aktivierst.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffae35">
        <td>
            <b>Unsichtbar:</b>
        </td><td>
            <input onclick="toggle('hinweis_invisible', 'invisible');" type="checkbox"  id="invisible" name="invisible"> unsichtbar einloggen <img src="images/prem_small.gif" alt="prem_small" height="12"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2" id="hinweis_invisible" style="background:#fff;font-size:9px;display:none;" bgcolor="#ffae35">
             Wenn du Premium-User bist, dann loggst du dich dieses mal unsichtbar ein. Du erscheinst dann als OFFLINE und man sieht dich nicht auf den Profilbesuchern.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffb442">
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <p></p><a href="sendpassword.php"><strong>Passwort vergessen?</strong></a></p>
            <p></p><input type="hidden" id="hash" name="hash" value=""><input id="loginsubmit" type="submit" value="Absenden"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p align="center">
    <b>Hinweis:</b> Cookies und Javascript m&uuml;ssen aktiviert sein!<br/> 
    <a href="http://hilfe.xyz.de/faq/doku.php/das_login_funktioniert_nicht"><b>Probleme beim Login?</b></a>
</p>
<p align="center"><a href="/registrieren.php"><img src="/images/teaser.gif"></a></p>
</form>
```

Well... as you can see, there is only 1 form to fill, but the field for username has no "id".

Secondly, there is a button to click to confirm the login data.

I have tried this:

```
my $a = WWW::Mechanize->new( 
     cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new( file => "./cookies.txt" ) 
     );

$a->get("$FLUserProfileLoginURL$FLuserID");
unless($a->success()) {
  print "Problem while loading site...\n\n";
        exit;
    }
$dest = $a->response->content;

@FORMS = $a->forms;

for $entry (@FORMS) {
   print Dumper ($entry);
}
```

It shows:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'default_charset' => 'UTF-8',
             'enctype' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             'accept_charset' => 'UNKNOWN',
             'action' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://www.xyz.de/login.php')}, 'URI::http' ),
             'method' => 'POST',
             'attr' => {
                         'onsubmit' => 'md5pass();',
                         'method' => 'post'
                       },
             'inputs' => [
                           bless( {
                                    'maxlength' => '40',
                                    'value_name' => '',
                                    'value' => '',
                                    'name' => 'user',
                                    'type' => 'text',
                                    'size' => '25'
                                  }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                           bless( {
                                    'readonly' => 1,
                                    'value_name' => '',
                                    'value' => '/profil.php?user=1180038',
                                    'name' => 'relocate',
                                    'type' => 'hidden'
                                  }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                           bless( {
                                    'maxlength' => '32',
                                    'value_name' => '',
                                    'name' => 'passwd',
                                    'id' => 'passwd',
                                    'type' => 'password',
                                    'size' => '25'
                                  }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                           bless( {
                                    'current' => 0,
                                    'menu' => [
                                                {
                                                  'seen' => 1,
                                                  'value' => undef,
                                                  'name' => 'off'
                                                },
                                                {
                                                  'value' => 'true',
                                                  'name' => 'automatisch einloggen'
                                                }
                                              ],
                                    'name' => 'setautologin',
                                    'onclick' => 'toggle(\'hinweis_setautologin\', \'setautologin\');',
                                    'id' => 'setautologin',
                                    'type' => 'checkbox'
                                  }, 'HTML::Form::ListInput' ),
                           bless( {
                                    'current' => 0,
                                    'menu' => [
                                                {
                                                  'seen' => 1,
                                                  'value' => undef,
                                                  'name' => 'off'
                                                },
                                                {
                                                  'value' => 'on',
                                                  'name' => 'unsichtbar einloggen prem_small'
                                                }
                                              ],
                                    'name' => 'invisible',
                                    'onclick' => 'toggle(\'hinweis_invisible\', \'invisible\');',
                                    'id' => 'invisible',
                                    'type' => 'checkbox'
                                  }, 'HTML::Form::ListInput' ),
                           bless( {
                                    'readonly' => 1,
                                    'value_name' => '',
                                    'value' => '',
                                    'name' => 'hash',
                                    'id' => 'hash',
                                    'type' => 'hidden'
                                  }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                           bless( {
                                    'value_name' => '',
                                    'value' => 'Absenden',
                                    'id' => 'loginsubmit',
                                    'type' => 'submit'
                                  }, 'HTML::Form::SubmitInput' )
                         ]
           }, 'HTML::Form' );
```

Unluckily, I am not able to send a correct "submit form" for this site.
Probably, the problem is, that there is a checkbox to activate, which calls "setautologin".

Any help would be great.

## UPDATE

I have tried it again with WWW::Mechanize::Shell, building a perl script after all...
First I used "get" to fetch login URL, then "fillout" to fill all the data.

Unfortunately, it throws me back to login.php.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller;
use URI::URL;

my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
my $formfiller = WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller->new();
$agent->env_proxy();

  $agent->get('http://www.xyz/login.php');
   $agent->form_number(1) if $agent->forms and scalar @{$agent->forms};
  $formfiller->add_filler( 'user' => Fixed => 'MyUsername' );
  $formfiller->add_filler( 'passwd' => Fixed => 'MyPassword' );
  $formfiller->add_filler( 'setautologin' => Fixed => 'true' );
  $formfiller->add_filler( 'invisible' => Fixed => 'off' );$formfiller->fill_form($agent->current_form);
  $agent->submit();
```

Probably there is a way to store cookies ???

Answer (score 1):

`WWW::Mechanize` will process all cookies for you automatically. So there is no need in such constructs:

```
cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new( file => "./cookies.txt" )
```

of course *if you don't want to load these cookies later into another script (or another run of the same script)*...

The main thing I see is Javascript's `md5pass()` function which (I believe) will set `hash` field in your form. So you just need to emulate this function in your code and submit this value:

```
$mech->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        user => $user,
        passwd => $password,
        hash => $hash,
    },
);
```

Comment: Many thanks so far... But... how I can generate the $hash variable ?? Is it a md5 over "username" & password" or only "password" ???
Regards

Comment: $hash = md5_hex($FLPASSWORD);       does it all... After this, your script modificatin works like charm. Many, many thanks !!!